# Generate a tabbed submenu — from taxonomy term or submenu item — with sample content

Tags: wp-query, menus, navigation, sub-menu, tabs

I'm looking to generate a tabbed submenu from taxonomy term or submenu item and include sample content (three items per term/submenuu item). The styling I can do, the problem is the html generation.

I see this style called tabbed submenus, fat menus, or mega menus. A good sample is the tabbed submenus at [Vice.com](http://vice.com). The end result looks like this:

```
Home | Taxonomy1 | Taxonomy2 | Taxonomy3 | CustomMenu
——————————————————           —————————————————————————
T2term1|   (content1 image)   (content2 image)  (content3 image)
T2term2<   Content1 Title     Content2 Title    Content3 Title
T2temr3|           Link: See All Stories in T2Term2
```

One issue is that three of our menus are essentially all terms for three custom taxonomies while the fourth is a custom menu made from admin-selected terms in tags taxonomy.

We've purchased Max Mega Menus as a possible solution only to find out it doesn't support tabbed submenus.

I'm finding the options are to buy a more expensive plugin that may or may not work (and definitely will have a CSS fight with our Zurb Foundation based theme) or find custom code that perhaps we can drop into the Foundation menus or into Max Mega Menu.

Any pointers appreciated — I'm finding this hard to solve with Google searches since the terminology is not set and every shady plugin author wants to sell a (possibly outdated) solution without a trial and a lot of plugins seem like ripoffs of other plugins.

Comment: What part of it is the issue, exactly? The top-level with the custom menu or the sub-level(s) with terms and images?

Comment: The issue is generating all the HTML under the top level menu items: submenu item list, tabs, and recent content per term.

Comment: Sounds like a task for a custom walker. You can do a lot by checking the `$object -> object` and `$depth` inside the `start_el` function. Take a look at the general menu example on the codex page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example

Comment: I ended up solving this with Ubermenu. It's a paid product and pretty robust.

Comment: @Slam You can add an answer yourself and accept it - that way this question won't show up as unanswered ;) You could outline a bit why/how Ubermenu helped exactly.

Comment: I don't think I had enough privileges to answer my own question which is why I did it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem with Ubermenu.

What I wanted to write was complex enough that it made more sense to get a tested, commercial plugin that had the features I need. MaxMegaMenu didn't do tabbed content but Ubermenu does.

I'm able to construct menus like this:

```
Taxonomy1
  [Tabs]
    [DynamicTerms]
      [Dynamic Posts]
Taxonomy2
  [Tabs]
    [DynamicTerms]
      [Dynamic Posts]
```

etc. The end result looks great, it integrated well enough with my custom theme (though I had to convert their LESS to SASS for Foundation compatibility), it does sticky and mobile menus as well, and it's well supported.